# error in viewing variable and function

Tags: php, output

i have this code :

```
<?php

function random(){
echo rand(0,50);
};

for (
$x = 1;
$x <= 20;
$x++){
    echo $x." : ".random()."<br>";
};

?>
```

and this is some outputs

> 23**1** : 
>   23**2** : 
>   9**3** : 
>   8**4** : 
>   1**5** :

it should be :

> 1 : 23
>  2 : 23
>  3 : 9
>  4 : 8
>  5 : 1

Comment: The random function executes before the concatenation; and echoes its result; so get your random function to return the value that can be concatenated into your echo statement inside the loop `function random(){
return rand(0,50);
};
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `echo rand(0,50);`. you need to use `return rand(0,50);`, See below:-

```
<?php

function random(){
return rand(0,50);
};

for (
$x = 1;
$x <= 20;
$x++){
    echo $x." : ".random()."<br>";
};

?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/397980

Note:- a correct explanation is given by @Mark Baker:-

`echo rand(0,50);`will going to executes before the concatenation, and hens you will get its output first and then your `$x` value. So get your random function to return the value that can be concatenated into your echo statement inside the loop

Comment: *Note:- [...]* You are too lazy to explain this... ?! (What do you do, if Mark Baker deletes his comment?)

Comment: I added the comment ,with a bit change. thanks for your suggestion @Rizier123